# Labeling points, that a generated within a unit circle

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

Suppose we want to generate labels with a unit circle.

What is done: I generated the first point within a unit circle and label it 1. I generated second point within a unit circle and label it 0.

Rest k-2 points I want to label in a following way: if a point lies in a half of a circle 1 -> it's labeled 1. If in a half of a circle 0 -> then it's label 0. So it means, that after generating first 2 points I need to draw a line through the centre of a circle that separates first two point. After that we compare newly generated point to this line and label it. How can I do thin in Python?

Comment: Which out of the uncountably many lines that separate the two points do you want to pick? What if the two points and the center of the circle are collinear?

Comment: This all depends on where you're splitting the circle in half too

Comment: @wjm 1)it doesn't matter which one. It just have to split points into different half circles. 2)Can happen, but it is highly unlikely

Comment: @Sayse Doesn't matter, it just has to split first two points into different half circles

Comment: You can save the first two angles, say `a0` and `a1`. Given an angle `ak`, you can set the label to `0` if `(a0 - ak) % (2 * np.pi) < (a1 - ak) % (2 * np.pi)` and `1` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save one of the two angles, call it `saved_angle`, and for all points `x`, `y`, check whether `x * np.sin(saved_angle) - y * np.cos(saved_angle) < 0`. Here is a code example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.xlim([-1, 1])
plt.ylim([-1, 1])

# Get two random points, saving the angle of one.

length = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2)
x = np.sqrt(length) * np.cos(angle)
y = np.sqrt(length) * np.sin(angle)
plt.plot([x], [y], 'ko')

length = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
saved_angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2)
x = np.sqrt(length) * np.cos(saved_angle)
y = np.sqrt(length) * np.sin(saved_angle)
plt.plot([x], [y], 'ko')

# Plot a bunch of random points, checking the condition.

for _ in range(100):
    length = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2)
    x = np.sqrt(length) * np.cos(angle)
    y = np.sqrt(length) * np.sin(angle)
    plt.plot([x], [y], 'bo' if x * np.sin(saved_angle) - y * np.cos(saved_angle) < 0 else 'ro')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

The idea is that after constructing the first two points `x[0,:]` and `x[1,:]`, labelled `y[0] = 0` and `y[1] = 1` respectively, you can construct a vector `n` perpendicular to the line which is the angle bisector of the angle between the vectors  `x[0,:]` and `x[1,:]`. That is why, this vector is constructed as

```
n = x[0,:] / norm(x[0,:])  -  x[1,:] / norm(x[1,:])
```

After that, a point that is on one side, the side in which `n` points, of the angle bisector, then the vector is labelled `0` and `1` if it i on the other side of the angle bisector. The dot product `n.dot(x[i,:]) > 0` means that `x[i,:]` is in the side of the angle bisector in which `n` points.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 12
x = np.empty((k, 2), dtype=float)
y = np.empty(k, dtype=int)
n = np.array([0.,0.])
for i in range(k):
    if i < 2:        
        angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2)
        x[i,:] = np.array([np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)])
        n = n + ((-1)**i) * x[i,:]
        length = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
        x[i,:] = np.sqrt(length)*x[i,:]
        y[i] = i
    else:
        angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2)
        length = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
        x[i,:] = np.array([np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)])
        if n.dot(x[i,:]) > 0: 
            y[i] = 0 
        else: 
            y[i] = 1
        x[i,:] = np.sqrt(length) * x[i,:]



s = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 150 )
xc = np.cos( s )
yc = np.sin( s )

xl = np.linspace( -1, 1, 150)  
yl = (- n[0]/n[1]) * xl


figure, axes = plt.subplots( 1 )

axes.plot( xc, yc )
axes.plot(0, 0)
axes.plot( xl, yl )

axes.plot(x[y==1, 0], x[y==1, 1], 'ro')
axes.plot(x[y==0, 0], x[y==0, 1], 'bo')

axes.set_aspect( 1 )  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! But what does n variable mean?

Comment: @LiverToll92 I added an explanation in my answer.